# The number of trials which maximizes the expectation of difference between the number of red balls and blue balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $N$ balls with $K$ red balls and $N-K$ blue balls. 
It means that the probability that the red ball is drawn with one draw is $K/N$.

There is a random variables

$X$ = the number of red balls drawn.

$Y$ = the number of blue balls drawn.

$Z$ = $X-Y$.

When I draw $M$ balls without replacement from $N$ balls ($K$ red balls and $N-K$ blue balls),
how can I find the proper $M$ which maximizes expectation $\mathbb{E}[Z]$?

Comment: What have you **tried**? Have you tried caculating $\Bbb P(Z=i)$ for any $i$ and $M$ for example, or have you tried finding $\Bbb E(Z)$ for small values of M?

Comment: Since $K<<N$ I assume $K<N/2$ in which case drawing $M>0$ balls without replacement always gives $\mathbb{E}[Z]<0$, but $M=0$ gives $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I want to find the value of $M$. If $K<<N$, i think that the proper value of $M$ maximizing $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ is $0$. My question is that $M$ which maximizes the $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ can be expressed with parameter $N,K$?

Comment: It seems the relation $E(Z) = E(X)-E(Y)$ might be relevant here.